# Download stuff under URL path

Tags: websites, mirrors, httrack

Suppose I have certain pages, e.g. www.abc.def/ghi/a.html; how can I download
all the pages under www.abc.def/ghi using httrack? (i.e. www.abc.def/ghi/a.html,
www.abc.def/ghi/b, ...)?
Right now, I'm using the simple `httrack http://www.abc.def/ghi/ -O
<output-folder>` command, but it fails with some sites.

E.g., when I try it with http://www.getsidekick.com/blog/ , it doesn't
download anything. However, if I'm using http://www.getsidekick.com/blog (note
the missing final slash), it downloads all the content under
http://www.getsidekick.com/blog/, but at the same time even content under
http://www.getsidekick.com/.
I don't know what the problem could be (maybe the fact that they haven't the `.html` extension?? e.g. http://www.getsidekick.com/blog/ultradian-rhythm-pomodoro-technique) and I haven't found a working solution in the manual or on their official forum.

Also, I already know how to do it with `wget`, but I'd like to accomplish the same thing with `httrack`.
So, is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's following every link on the page, and there is a link back to the top level.

Try using `wget` with recursive and no-parent options.

```
wget -r  --no-parent http://www.getsidekick.com/blog
```

Comment: sorry, maybe I should have add this to the question, but I already know how to do it with `wget`, but I'd like to accomplish the same thing with `httrack`.

Comment: I tried to fix your code, but it's less than 6 character, so I can't. It should be `--no-parent`.
Btw, I tried your code also and, even if it downloads a lot of stuffs, it doesn't download important pages.
E.g. the page http://www.getsidekick.com/blog/stop-procrastinating-stay-focused isn't downloaded at all. Why do you think it happens?